# Unable to understand a permission warning in Mac

Tags: macos, macports, pager

I have 777 permissions for the app AquaLess installed by MacPorts.

I run

./AquaLess.app

I get

```
zsh: permission denied: ./AquaLess.app
```

This is a strange warning, since I have 777 permissions.

**How can you use the program installed by MacPorts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could run:

```
$ ./AquaLess.app/Contents/MacOS/AquaLess
```

Which runs the actual executable within the .app bundle.

Comment: Your answer suggests me that I need to put the following PATH to my PATH: /Applicatios/MacPorts/*/Contents/MacOS/

Comment: The command in my PATH however does not work. It suggests me that I cannot use * in my PATH. Thus, it seems that the only solution is to separately add each program to my PATH.

Comment: You cannot use wildcards in PATH.

Answer (score 6):

Type `open AquaLess.app`

A file with `.app` extension isn't an executable file. It's a directory that contains various resources in ways that Mac OS knows how to open.

You would get the same warning if you tried to execute $HOME.